# Recursive subtraction does not work

Tags: recursion, lisp, clisp

I wrote a function for recursive subtraction in lisp, but when i load it and run the function with numbers for example `( subtract 4 3 )` the output is `-3` which I do not understand why.

```
(defun subtract (x y)
  (if (eq y 0) 
    x
    (- 1 (subtract x (- y 1) ) ) ) )
```

Comment: http://www.gregfjohnson.com/pred/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fixed version of your code:

```
(defun subtract (x y)
  (if (zerop y) 
    x
    (subtract (1- x) (1- y))))
```

Notice that in the recursive call we subtract 1 from *both* `x` (to actually decrement the number) and `y` (to get it closer to the base case, 0).

Answer (score 3):

First, don't use `eq` to compare numbers. It accidentally works in this case, because your numbers happen to be small. Either use `=`, or (since you're looking for zero) `zerop`.

Second, you can use `(trace subtract)` to see a trace of invocations and return values.

Third, `(- 1 x)` and `(- x 1)` have, in the general case, very different values.